# why is the second point displayed in the wrong place?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I am trying to write a function to draw a triangle (it's in main() now). everything works - everything is cool, but I added the execution of two functions for drawing point ( drawPoint()) and the point that is drawn after the triangle is displayed in the wrong place, why?

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
    the rgb
    </title>
</head>

<body onload="main()">
<canvas id="webgl" width="400" height="400">
PLZ USE BROWSER SUPPORTING CANVAS
</canvas>

<script src="../lib/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/webgl-debug.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/cuon-utils.js"></script>
<script src="thergb.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

thergb.js:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('webgl');
var gl = getWebGLContext(canvas);

function main()
{
    
    clearCanvas('green');
    drawPoint(0.3,0.0,50.0,'blue'); //draw point before triangle
    
    //draw triangle
    var VSHADER_SOURCE=
        'attribute vec4 a_Position;\n'+
        'void main() {\n' +
        ' gl_Position = a_Position;\n'+
        '}\n';
    var FSHADER_SOURCE=
        'void main() {\n' +
        ' gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n'+
        '}\n';
    if(!initShaders(gl, VSHADER_SOURCE, FSHADER_SOURCE))
        {
            return;
        }

    var n = initVertexBuffers(gl);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, n);

    drawPoint(0.4,0.0,50.0,'red'); //draw point after triangle

    
    

}
function initVertexBuffers(gl) {
  var vertices = new Float32Array([
    0, 0.5,   -0.5, -0.5,   0.5, -0.5
  ]);
  var n = 3; // The number of vertices

  // Create a buffer object
  var vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  if (!vertexBuffer) {
    console.log('Failed to create the buffer object');
    return -1;
  }

  // Bind the buffer object to target
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
  // Write date into the buffer object
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  var a_Position = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Position');
  if (a_Position < 0) {
    console.log('Failed to get the storage location of a_Position');
    return -1;
  }
  // Assign the buffer object to a_Position variable
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_Position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  // Enable the assignment to a_Position variable
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Position);

  return n;
}
function drawPoint(x,y,size,color)
{
    var VSHADER_SOURCE=
        'attribute vec4 a_Position;\n'+
        'attribute float a_PointSize;\n'+
        'void main() {\n' +
        ' gl_Position = a_Position;\n'+
        ' gl_PointSize = a_PointSize;\n'+
        '}\n';      

    if (color == 'red')
    {
        var FSHADER_SOURCE=
        'void main() {\n' +
        ' gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n'+
        '}\n';
    }
    if (color == 'green')
    {
        var FSHADER_SOURCE=
        'void main() {\n' +
        ' gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n'+
        '}\n';
    }
    if (color == 'blue')
    {
        var FSHADER_SOURCE=
        'void main() {\n' +
        ' gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);\n'+
        '}\n';      
    }

    if(!initShaders(gl, VSHADER_SOURCE, FSHADER_SOURCE))
        {
            return;
        }
    var a_Position = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Position');
    var a_PointSize = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_PointSize');
    gl.vertexAttrib3f(a_Position,x,y,0.0);
    gl.vertexAttrib1f(a_PointSize, size);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0,1);
}

function clearCanvas(color)
{
    if (color == 'red')
    {
        gl.clearColor( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
    if (color == 'green')
    {
        gl.clearColor( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
    if (color == 'blue')
    {
        gl.clearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    }
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}
```

additional libraries are on my github: https://github.com/bazylevnik0/thergb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the point after the triangle shows up in the wrong place is that when the triangle is drawn it enables the attributes with `gl.enableVertexAttribArray`

An enabled attribute gets its values from a buffer assigned when calling `gl.vertexAttribPointer`

A disabled attribute gets its value from a constant set by `gl.vertexAttrib???`

In `drawPoint`, the `gl.vertexAttrib3f` functions, they set the constant for that attribute, but when it comes time to draw the second point the attributes are enabled which means it's looking in the buffers assigned when the triangle was drawn not the constant.

If you add

```
    gl.disableVertexAttribArray(a_Position);
    gl.disableVertexAttribArray(a_PointSize);
```

in `drawPoint` before drawing it should work.

You might find [this state diagram](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/resources/webgl-state-diagram.html) helpful in understanding what is being set by the various functions